# Pass a same models to a single View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a student Model.This model have Functions in its controller like this:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = obj.GetStudentlist();

            return View(model);
        }
        public ActionResult ScheduleStudentList(string id)
        {
            var model = obj.GetStudentlistOfSchedule(id);

            return View(model);
        }
```

So **Index controller** return a list that contain all of students,but **ScheduleStudentList** controller again return a list of students with a specific id.

So my problem is i have a view for index  controller and i want to pass the **ScheduleStudentList** list to Index's view.because both of these controller return a same model .what should i do ?

My Index view code :

```
@model IEnumerable<DomainClasses.Student>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IntNo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FatherName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BirthLocation)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Birthday)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImageUrl)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Major)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Degree)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IdentNo)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Mobile)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Password)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RegisterDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.State)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IntNo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FatherName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BirthLocation)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Birthday)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageUrl)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Major)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Degree)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdentNo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mobile)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Password)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RegisterDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State)
        </td>
         <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {  id=item.Id  }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id  })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Best Regards

Comment: could you post some code for these views?

Comment: Ok.you can see it .i sent it

Comment: return View("Index", model);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the Index View by returning

```
return View("Index", model);
```

from your ScheduleStundentList(string id) method.